# GitHub Pages - frontmatter causes page to break

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, yaml-front-matter

I am publishing pages from my `/docs` folder as per https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing

If I include this front matter on a page, the build breaks.

```
---
layout: page
title: "Help Page"
permalink: /help
---
```

The page is built but only contains the data from the `<body>` element. No headers, no stylesheet, just garbled HTML.  The same occurs if I use `layout: post`.

[image]

If I removed the line `layout: page` then everything works.

According to the GitHub documentation - https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-jekyll/ - I should be able to use this frontmatter in my pages.

What blindingly obvious thing have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "slate" theme only has a "default" layout.

So switching to `layout: default` fixed the issues.